# Set textView color programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-studio

this code shows the text:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_detail, container, false);
    if (mItem != null) {
        TextView txtBig = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.item_detail2);
        txtBig.setText(mItem.content);
    }

    return rootView;
}
```

but when I use:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_detail, container, false);
        if (mItem != null) {
            TextView txtBig = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.item_detail2);
            txtBig.setText(mItem.content);
            txtBig.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
        }
        return rootView;
    }
```

there is no text on the screen. I've tried `txtBig.setTextColor(0xff000000);` too , but no luck.

Comment: from what I am seeing the mistake is `if (mItem != null)` . You probably forgot to initalize it

Comment: @Blackbelt , it is initialized, the first code works, but when I add color property it doesn't render the text.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try below code:

```
txtBig.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.yellow));
```

You have to **add** yellow color in **color.xml** in **Resources** -> **Value** Directory.

```
<color name="yellow">#FFFF00</color>
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: thanks, this doesn't work for me, but when I changed the order of codes, it works. should I first set the thextColor and after that set the text content?!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like, the color of your text and the background where the text is actually rendered are same. Can you change the color of the text and see if the text is visible?

```
txtBig.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
```

Comment: No, the background is white